# How to hide zip files in a jpg file in Ubuntu?

Tags: zip

I need a way to hide zip files in a file .

Example i have a 1.zip , 2.zip ,3.zip contain data

I need to concatenates them in a new file called example.jpg.

Is there a way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Open Terminal**

**2. Cd to the zips location (example : cd /test ) where i put them there .**

1. **type** `cat 1.zip 2.zip 3.zip > example.jpg`

A file example.jpg is created , it seems to be corrupted but in real it contain the 3 zip files with there date .

You can now delete the files (1.zip ,2.zip,3.zip)

To extract them from the example.jpg :

```
unzip example.jpg -d /destinationyouwant
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: At first I thought that this wouldn't possibly work, but indeed, it does. `unzip` seems to process the archinve even if it is in fact multiple archives into a single one.

Comment: sure, but what does the image look like?

Comment: you do realize that anyone that ever heard of the "file" command can see through this?

Answer (score 6):

Hiding secret information in images is a topic of [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography). Some linux tools which deal with hiding information in images:

- steghide (`sudo apt-get install steghide`)
- stepic (`sudo apt-get install python-stepic`)
- outguess(`sudo apt-get install outguess`)

---

Using `steghide`:

Steghide supports BMP and JPG images. To embed a `secret.zip` file in a `cover.jpg` and make a new file for the embedded `jpg` use

```
steghide --embed -ef secret.zip -cf cover.jpg -sf embedded.jpg
```

`steghide` will prompt for a password, type in one, this will be needed to recover the secret. After this you can view `embedded.jpg` just like a normal picture, you won't really notice that it is manipulated.

To recover the secret run

```
steghide --extract -sf embedded.jpg
```

Type in the password and your secret will be recovered with its original name, `secret.zip`.

An important thing to know that an image can only contain a certain amount of secret data, since putting a lot of data into the image would need too much manipulations on the image and the image will be no more like the original. To view how much secret data can `steghide` embed in a certain image, run:

```
steghide --info cover.jpg
```

For other features of `steghide` look in `man steghide`.

---

With `python-stepic` you use these commands:

- for embedding:

  ```
  stepic --encode -t secret.zip -i cover.png -o embedded.png
  ```
- for extracting:

  ```
  stepic --decode -i embedded.png -o recovered.zip
  ```

`stepic` uses the Python Image Library so it should work with most of the image formats, but `png` is recommended for the output image format by the authors. For more info on `stepic` go [here](http://domnit.org/stepic/doc/).